# Looking for an embed webview on android application

Tags: android, cordova, webview, crosswalk

I am working on a Android application which is using webview as the main UI. (I don't use Cordova in this project.) The problem of the webview is that it gives different behaviors on running on different android devices. Some devices don't support latest features of javascript or css. In order to unify them I am looking for a solution to embed a webview inside my android application. I see crosswalk may be a good solution for me to choose. But I am not sure whether it is the best one. Is there any other frameworks support the same solution? My requirement is described below:

- The current android project is created under Android Studio and use gradle to build the application. I want to keep that when using embed webview.
- the solution should not require a lot of structure changes on my android application.
- It could run on most of android devices. Ideally support android 4.4 and above.
- The embed webview can be easily enabled/disabled.

Comment: in what versions of android are you having problems? According to google any device with android 4.4 and above will run on chromium webview.

Comment: I have problem running promise javascript code in android 4.4.2.